# Windows Named Pipes and Multithreading

Tags: c#, winapi, named-pipes

I have two processes that communicate through a single named pipe in duplex and binary mode (not message). Each process has two threads, one that writes to and one that reads from the pipe. Reading and writing at each end of the pipe are not synchronized so I read and write truly parallel. Each sender numbers its messages. All code is written in C#. I use interop and Win32 for creating and connecting the pipes.

I have a unit test in MSTest that starts a server and client and spawns two threads, one sending messages server->client and one sending from client->server.

Problem: Seldom, some actually unique messages are received twice or more often.

Question: Can a duplex pipe on windows handle multithreading like described above? Or do I need to synchronize the read/writes at one end of the pipe?

**UPDATE**
A full duplex pipe used with synchronous IO works in both directions but not at the same time. Concurrent read/writes on one end of the pipe will definitely produce wrong results. It seems a call to WriteFile wakes up the blocked ReadFile thread. My workaround was using two unidirectional pipes. This is also recommended somewhere else. Maybe it works with overlapped IO, I didn't try.

Comment: Lots of ways to blow your foot off when you use threads.  *Never* assume that code that's used by hundreds of thousands of programmers and half a billion machines is the cause of the problem.  This is not a problem caused by the pipes.

Comment: It's not that I think the pipes are the problem. I'm questioning my understanding of the API. So pipes are able to handle the described scenario. Somewhere else I read a recommendation using two unidirectional pipes instead of one duplex and I don't know why I should.

Comment: You know there's `System.IO.Pipes` right?

Comment: Ohh, I thought it's just available in 3.5, not client profile. But it seems it's contained?